# Crossing times of processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Suppose that $X_t$ and $\tilde{X}_t$ are processes defined on the stochastic basis $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}_t,\mathbb{P})$ such that

- for any time $t>0$, $1>p_t>0$, where $p_t$ is defined by
  $$
  p_t\triangleq \mathbb{P}\left(
  \int_0^t X_s ds> \int_0^t \tilde{X}_s ds 
  \right)
  ,
  $$
  (assuming the integrals are well defined).
- $X_0<\tilde{X}_0$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.

Define the hitting time $\tau$ by
$$
\tau \triangleq \inf\left\{
t>0 : X_t >\tilde{X}_t
\right\}.
$$

How can we compute $\tau$?

Comment: I think you are missing an $\inf$ in the definition of $\tau$.

Comment: Thanks, that seems more reasonable